# how to make a lot of parameters available to the entire system?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have objects from various classes that work together to perform a certain task. The task requires a lot of parameters, provided by the user (through a configuration file). The parameters are used deep inside the system.

I have a choice of having the controller object read the configuration file, and then allocate the parameters as appropriate to the next layer of objects, and so on in each layer. But the only objects themselves know which parameters they need, so the controller object would need to learn a lot of detail about every other object.

The other choice is to bundle all the parameters into a collection, and pass the whole collection into every function call (equivalently, create a global object that stores them, and is accessible to everyone). This looks and feels ugly, and would cause a variety of minor technical issues (e.g., I can't allow two objects to use parameters with the same name; etc.)

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the "global collection" alternative in the past.

If you are concerned with naming: how would you handle this in your config file?  The way I see it, your global collection is a datastructure representing the same information you have in your config file, so if you have a way of resolving or avoiding name clashes in your cfg-file, you can do the same in your global collection.

Comment: You are right about the cfg-file name clashes. I guess *whether* having this cfg-file is a good idea is part of the question... Not that I see any alternative

Comment: if you have really many parameters, it makes sense to partition the config name-space in some way to make it more manageable.  In the cfg-file you could do this with sections (for example with headings like [this], like the old windows .ini-files) or prefixes (heading.subheading.parameter) or use a full-fledged hierarchic structure like XML.  Your config-object could be structured the same way, where you could pass to the function only the relevant subtree.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't feel like I'm thread-jacking you - what you're asking about is similar to what I was thinking about in terms of property aggregation to avoid the models you want to avoid.

I also nicked a bit of the declarative vibe that Elixir has turned me onto.

I'd be curious what the Python gurus of stack overflow think of it and what better alternatives there might be. I don't like big kwargs and if I can avoid big constructors I prefer to.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import inspect
from itertools import chain, ifilter
from pprint import pprint
from abc import ABCMeta

class Property(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self._x = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._x)

    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value

    def delx(self):
        del self._x

    value = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the property.")

class BaseClass(object):

    unique_baseclass_thing = Property()

    def get_prop_tree(self):
        mro = self.__class__.__mro__
        r = []
        for i in xrange( 0, len(mro) - 1 ):

            child_prop_names = set(dir(mro[i]))
            parent_prop_names = set(dir(mro[i+1]))

            l_k = list( chain( child_prop_names - parent_prop_names ) )
            l_n = [ (x, getattr(mro[i],x,None)) for x in l_k ]
            l_p = list( ifilter(lambda y: y[1].__class__ == Property, l_n))

            r.append(
                (mro[i],
                    (dict
                        ( l_p )
                    )
                )
            )
        return r

    def get_prop_list(self):
        return list( chain(* [ x[1].items() for x in reversed( self.get_prop_tree() ) ] ) )


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    unique_subclass_thing = Property(1)

class SubSubClass(SubClass):
    unique_subsubclass_thing_one = Property("blah")
    unique_subsubclass_thing_two = Property("foo")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = SubSubClass()

    for b in a.get_prop_tree():
        print '---------------'
        print b[0].__name__
        for prop in b[1].keys():
            print "\t", prop, "=", b[1][prop].value
        print

    for prop in a.get_prop_list():
```

When you run it..

---

```
SubSubClass
    unique_subsubclass_thing_one = blah
    unique_subsubclass_thing_two = foo

---------------
SubClass
    unique_subclass_thing = 1

---------------
BaseClass
    unique_baseclass_thing = None

unique_baseclass_thing None
unique_subclass_thing 1
unique_subsubclass_thing_one blah
unique_subsubclass_thing_two foo
```

Comment: I don't mind at all. Though, I'm not sure if many people realize that you're asking a question.

Comment: Well, I'm asking a question as much as I'm answering one - this is my approach to what you're trying to do.. There's a lot of ways to skin a cat (so to speak..) just do a stack overflow search on 'python singleton' to see what I mean. :p

Comment: I am quite interested in your approach. But how would you adapt it to my situation?